# wxpython- Color on Bitmap on toolbar not appearing

Tags: python, wxpython

```
def createColorTool(self, toolbar, color):
  bmp = self.MakeBitmap(color)
  newId = wx.NewId()
  label=''
  tool = toolbar.AddRadioTool(newId, label,bmp, shortHelp=color)
  self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.OnColor, tool)
 def MakeBitmap(self, color):
  bmp= wx.EmptyBitmap(16, 15)
  
  dc = wx.MemoryDC()
  dc.SelectObject(bmp)
  
  dc.SetBackground(wx.Brush(color))
  
  dc.SelectObject(wx.NullBitmap)
  return bmp
```

The color attribute takes in color from a list of colors {'black', 'blue', 'green'} the problem is program is working fine but for bitmap, in the toolbar, only black color is being displayed not any other color as specified in the list for the choose color option.
You can see the image here of how the code is working

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I get lost with `DC` manipulation, so here's an alternative.
This assumes that `color` is a `wx.Colour` e.g. `wx.Colour(0, 155, 255, alpha=255)`

```
def MakeBitmap(self, color):
    bmp = wx.Bitmap.FromRGBA(16, 15, color.red, color.green, color.blue, color.alpha)
    return bmp
```

Creates the Green square below

[image]

Edit:
Your code sets the background brush but doesn't use it.
So you are returning the bare bones bitmap.

If you must use a `dc` try the following:

```
def MakeBitmap(self, color):
    bmp = wx.Bitmap(16, 15)
    dc = wx.MemoryDC(bmp)
    dc.SetBackground(wx.Brush(color))
    dc.Clear()
    return bmp
```

or:

```
def MakeBitmap(self, color):
    bmp= wx.Bitmap(16, 15)
    dc = wx.MemoryDC()
    dc.SelectObject(bmp)
    dc.SetBackground(wx.Brush(color))
    dc.Clear()
    return bmp
```

> Clear(self)
> Clears the device context using the current background brush.

Comment: Thanks @Rolf that actually works. But I am still wondering problem with the DC manipulation part. It gives issues in other programs as well

Comment: Thank you @Rolf it is working now. The use of dc.Clear() to clear the device context with current background really does the trick.

Comment: @UtkarshSingh Happy to help, welcome to StackOverflow - https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers